# C# - Get days between 2 dates

Tags: c#, datetime

My case scenario is User selects a financial year say 1-Jan-2015 to 31-Dec-2015. Then he selects days say 'SATURDAY','SUNDAY'.

I want to fetch all the dates between the above criteria.

I can get the dates like this :-

```
    ....
    for (var date = fromDate; date <= toDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
         temp.Add(date);
```

But How to get only days 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY' from the date range?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
 for (var date = fromDate; date <= toDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
 {
     if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) 
            temp.Add(date);
 }
```

In case if set of days of week is not static:

```
HashSet<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek = new HashSet<DayOfWeek> { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday };
List<DateTime> temp = new List<DateTime>();
for (var date = fromDate.Date; date <= toDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
    if (daysOfWeek.Contains(date.DayOfWeek))
        temp.Add(date);
```

Comment: `DayOfWeek` is different everytime. In case if it is different then?

Comment: @Backs Oh, wasn't needed, but thanks ;D. Stack Overflow is the reason I can write some program lol, I just answer some as thanks :D

Comment: If User selects `Day` as `Monday` or `Tuesday` or may be all the days of the week, then above code will not do. How to handle then?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov `HashSet` should be the simpler solution than building a new `DayOfWeek` flag

Comment: @Anup is this answer correct for you or I should improve it?

Answer (score 6):

```
var fromDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
var toDate = new DateTime(2015, 2, 15);
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(toDate - fromDate).TotalDays + 1)
    .Select(i => fromDate.AddDays(i))
    .Where(i => i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);


foreach(var date in dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd ddd}", date);
}
```

[.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xw36RN)

Answer (score 0):

The loop is simple and does the job, but Linq is more fun.

But @Eric: Why the flag thing? You can select the weekdays directly:

```
DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
DateTime toDate = new DateTime(2015, 2, 15);
DateTime[] dates = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)toDate.Subtract(fromDate).TotalDays + 1)
    .Select(i => fromDate.AddDays(i))
    .Where(i => (i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || i.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)).ToArray();


foreach(DateTime date in dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd ddd}", date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TimeSpan` class

```
timespan p = new timespan();
p = dt2-dt1;
MessageBox.Show(p.days.tostring());
```